# Activity has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$Connection

Tags: android, exception, selfbrailleclient

My Android app has a Webview inside a Fragment, the Webview is displaying a simple HTML document. When I quit the app, the logcat show the following error:

```
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420): Activity com.abc.test.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$Connection@66247648 that was originally bound here
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.abc.test.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$Connection@66247648 that was originally bound here
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:989)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:883)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1649)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1632)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient.doBindService(SelfBrailleClient.java:125)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient.access$1000(SelfBrailleClient.java:43)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$SelfBrailleHandler.handleRebindService(SelfBrailleClient.java:260)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$SelfBrailleHandler.handleMessage(SelfBrailleClient.java:245)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-06 10:58:29.468: E/ActivityThread(420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
```

I try to search the error on the net but no luck. Does anybody know what is this exception for?

I am using the following device to test:

```
Device: LG G2 (F320S21d)
Android Version: 4.4.2
Runtime Mode: ART
```

Comment: I'm having a (very) similar issue. Almost the exact same scenario. G2 4.4.2 I'm also using fragments, but not for the webview. Could this be a device specific bug? Did you ever find what was causing it?

Comment: @Hanon Did you got answer. Kindly share here, i too facing the same problem on phonegap application.

Comment: I get this error on G2 too. No webview

Answer (score 1):

You need some code on life cycle onDestory()

```
if(webview ! = null) { webview.destory(); webview == null;}
```